# JavaScript + addEventListener 'click' ignored on select html object

Tags: javascript

I've added an eventListener on the document in hopes to hide myWidget whenever anything within the document is clicked (except for the widget of course).

```
myWidget.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
}, false);

document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    myWidget.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Now this seems to work on everything but select html objects.  Selecting a select box shows the select content, but the widget is not hidden and the console.log never fires.  Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `change` event

```
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    myWidget.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Comment: Change does nothing. I'm attempting to hide the myWidget when a select object is clicked.